# Evaluate the following integral: $\int \frac{\arctan x}{(x-2)^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int \frac{\arctan x}{(x-2)^2} \,dx$$

My idea:

First of all, I tried to divide it into a multiplication of functions, therefore, applying the integration by parts I got the following form:
$$\frac{\arctan x}{2-x} - \int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(2-x)} dx$$

Here I am stuck in fact I tried to split this integral into multiplication of functions in order to use one more time integration by parts but I don't have any interesting result.

I would like to solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use this: $$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(2-x)}=\frac{1}{5}(\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{2-x})$$

Comment: Try partial fraction decomposition